# Errorhandling Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm not a master in Scripting, so I have to ask here :)

How can I implement an errorhandling for this:

```
find . -type f|sed 's_\.\/__' > $PATH
```

i.e. abort when this was not successfull.

Thank you very much in advance
Thomas

Comment: Can you define `this was not successful`? Regarding `find` or `sed`?

Comment: Can you tell us what could be not successful particularly?

Comment: You appear to be using the `PATH` variable to store a file name. Don't; it's a built-in shell parameter that stores a list of directories for command lookup. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

try to use conditions like && or ||

`find . -type f|sed 's_./__' > $PATH && if_true_do_something || if_false_do_something`

Answer (score 0):

First thing is your command would fail at least most certainly since $PATH is an invalid single path.

```
find . -type f | sed 's_\.\/__' > $PATH
```

If you want to check if both commands worked well, use the `pipefail` option which would make a pipe call return a nonzero status if any of the commands along the line return one, not just the last one.

```
set -o pipefail  ## You have this only once in the script.

find . -type f | sed 's_\.\/__'  > $PATH || {
    echo "Failed."
    exit 1  ## This probably is what you mean to abort.
}

# Shell script continues here...
```

An alternative:

```
...
find . -type f | sed 's_\.\/__' > $PATH
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Failed."
    exit 1
fi
```

Example:

```
> set +o pipefail  ## Disable pipefail (default).
> true | false
> echo $?
1
> false | true
> echo $?
0

> set -o pipefail  ## Enable pipefail.
> true | false
> echo $?
1
> false | true
> echo $?
1
```

Notice that the last command returned 1 even if `false` was not at the end. While when `pipefail` was disabled, the pipe command would still return 0 even though one of the commands (`false`) returned 1.